# Are there any rules about style inheritance in Mathematica?

Tags: output-formatting, gui-construction, style, inheritance

I can style every part of an UI separately. But it is not handy and it would be nice to have list of **Heads which are not inheriting at all or even partly**.

Are there any rules about inheritance?

```
Column[{
  "text",
  Panel["panel"],
  Framed["framed"],
  Dynamic["dynamic"],
  Button["button"],
  PopupMenu["", {}, "popupMenu_Default_Label"],
  PopupMenu[1, {1 -> "popupMenu_Value"}],
  Pane["Pane"],
  Graphics[Text@"graphics", Frame -> True]
  },
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 60, FontColor -> Red, FontWeight -> Bold}, 
 Spacings -> 0
 ]
```

> [image]

As we can see, sometimes everything is inherited, sometimes some things, like color but not font size and sometimes nothing.

Nice example is `PopupMenu` which does what it wants, and the best is `Framed` whose frame is colored according to `FontColor` :D

Comment: Apart from the frame being red - which appears to be a bug --I don't see too many surprises.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Who said anything about bugs? :) And yes Im not surprised either but it would be nice to have some clean description what is asked. For me it was confusing that everything behaves differently.

Comment: Off the top of my head base style is appended to other specific styles so that will never work. It would need to be prepended.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch What do you mean by "specific styles"? p.s. I'm not looking for some kind of setup for MMA as HTML+CSS is. I just want to create simple cheatsheet what user should expect.

Comment: away and on phone but by specific styles i mean the styles for popup, pane, panel and so on. I think you can put all this together from the docs but not all in one place as you want

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Yes, that's basically the same but with different words. "which wrappers have which style options built in?". This design makes code really crowded with unnecessary styling options.