# How change style of InputField in a Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, inputfield, style

Is it possible to specify a style, e.g., font size, for `InputField` type controls inside a `Manipulate` and if so, how?

For example, in the following the `BaseStyle` option to `Manipulate` changes the output font size but not the font size of the input fields:

```
Manipulate[
  y[t] /. First@
      DSolve[{a y''[t] + b y'[t] + c y[t] == r, y[t0] == ic, y'[t0] == icp}, y[t], t],
  {{a, 1}, "a"}, {{b, 1}, "b"}, {{c, 1}, "c"}, {{r, 0}, "r(t)"}, 
  {{t0, 0}, "t0"}, {{ic, 0}, "y[t0]"}, {{icp, 0}, "y'[t0]"}, 
  ControlType -> InputField, BaseStyle -> 16]
```

I tried the "obvious" way of using, e.g., `Style[a]` instead of `a` in the control-variable specification, but that's erroneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors. Here you have them corrected and an example on how to change each component styling:

```
Manipulate[
 y[t] /. First@ DSolve[{a y''[t] + b y'[t] + c y[t] == r, y[t0] == ic, y'[t0] == icp}, y[t], t],
 {{a, 1, "a"}},
 {{b, 1, "b"}},
 {{c, 1, "c"}},
 {{r, 0, "r(t)"}},
 {{t0, 0, "t0"}},
 {{ic, 0, "y[t0]"}},
 {{icp, 0, Style["y'[t0]", {16, Red}]}, BaseStyle -> 30},
 ControlType -> InputField, BaseStyle -> {16, Bold}]
```

[image: Mathem![Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Actually, and not considering how to change the style of the input fields, I don't think I had any syntax errors except in so far as the field labels are concerned; for that your revised syntax is correct.

Comment: Works nicely: thanks! (For the record, this was the first answer posted, but it was withdrawn temporarily before I got a chance to accept it and thank its author, @belisarius.)

Answer (score 1):

#### Quick answer

put it as a specification of the controller

```
Manipulate[x, {{x, 0}, 0, 100, BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 25}, ControlType -> InputField]
```

> [image]

#### Quick notes

- Nonuniform styles handling is really annoying, one have to always remember what can be inherited and what not or put explicit directives everywhere.

  I asked it already in [Are there any rules about style inheritance in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73015/5478)
- Here it is also strange because `BaseStyle` applies to *body* of a `Manipulate` and *labels*, not to controller even though that `Style[InputField[], 25]` can inherit `FontSize`.

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly. Since the only style parameter I need to change is the font size, the target of `BaseStyle` can be simplified a bit: `Manipulate[a, {{a, 1, Style["a", 16]}, BaseStyle -> 16}, 
 ControlType -> InputField]`

Comment: I, too, would sure like to see a convincing explanation of when and how styles are inherited.